# Can some explain in details about one sed command

Tags: sed

I didnt get the command `sed 's/^.*\(.\{4\}\)$/\1/'` what its doing. If someone could explain me per each character that would great and I can understand it very well. I am basic only with sed and learning it now only.

Comment: You need to do some research, show us what you have tried, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have two things going on, understanding `sed` and understanding the regular expression passed into the sed substitution command.

Let's start with the over all command:

```
sed 's/^.*\(.\{4\}\)$/\1/'
 ^   ^      ^          ^
 |   |      |          |- what you want to replace found text with
 |   |      |
 |   |      |- what you're looking for
 |   |    
 |   |- tell sed you want to substitute the text we find
 |      between the first two '/' with the contents between
 |      the last two '/'
 |
 |- call the sed application
```

Next up is understanding the regular expression. https://regex101.com/ is a great resource for this. First, let's look at the regular expression:

```
^.*\(.\{4\}\)$
```

You're sending this through the shell so there is some shell escaping going on. Let's remove the shell escaping to see the real regex:

```
^.*(.{4})$
```

Now this is a bit more clear. This regular expression:

1. matches the beginning of the line: `^`
2. followed by zero or more characters: `.*`
3. and capture the last 4 characters of the line: `(.{4})$`

   - the parenthesis create the capture group
   - `.` captures any character
   - `{4}` four times
   - `$` anchored by the end of the line

Lastly we have the `/\1/` portion of the sed command. This tells sed to replace whatever it found with `^.*(.{4})$` with everything found in the capture group created by `(.{4})$`.

So basically, this command replaces each line in a file with the last four characters found in that line.

Comment: Thank you so much for the more clear information. This will be very useful for me to get into the sed in depth.

Comment: @Ravikumar, you're welcome. Perhaps you can accept the answer if it has helped.

Comment: Huh? There is no shell escaping here; the script is in single quotes. The backslashes are required by this particular regex dialect.